# How to fix or balance the image with an white color overlay?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Hi all I have this image that has a white overlay on it, I am trying to equalize the color or in other words remove the white overlay so it is one color. I am new to image processing and I thought maybe to extract the color channel then using the equalize histogram it if that works? What would be the best approach to this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: do you need a general algorithm, or just this picture fixed? **do not** "equalize" the histogram. this is a linear blending of presumably white with the image, so the correction is also a linear/affine operation (addition/subtraction/multiplication/division)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz sorry for the confusion, yup I'm looking for an algorithm that solves this

Comment: ok, so first you need a mask for the region. then you would calculate histograms for inside and outside. assuming those histograms are supposed to be similar, then you'd try to match the inner histogram to the outer with a linear transformation. you can do that with brute force (exhaustively iterating over the parameters), or I think there's a more direct way via cumulative distribution functions (CDF). you should give it a try.

Comment: You could try to match the mean and standard deviation inside with that outside. See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/. You would need a mask to identify inside and outside the brighter rectangle to get the statistics as @Christoph Rackwitz said above.

Comment: Perhaps it would be adequate to simply equalize the means. So use the mask to get the mean values inside and outside. Get the difference. Then subtract the difference from the brighter center of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple attempt to match the mean of the inner region with that of the outer region. It does not work terribly well because it is a global change and does not take into account brightness variation across the image. But you can play around with it to start.

It takes a mask image and gets the means of the inner and outer regions. Then gets the difference and subtracts from the inner region.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image 
img = cv2.imread('writer.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# rectangle coordinates
x = 61
y = 8
w = 663
h = 401
    
# create mask for inner area
mask = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.uint8)
mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = 255

# compute means of inner rectangle region and outer region
mean_inner = np.mean(img[np.where(mask == 255)])
mean_outer = np.mean(img[np.where(mask == 0)])

# compute difference in mean values
bias = 0
diff = mean_inner - mean_outer + bias

# print mean of each
print("mean of inner region:", mean_inner)
print("mean of outer region:", mean_outer)
print("difference:", diff)

# subtract diff from img
img_diff = cv2.subtract(img, diff)

# blend with original using mask
result = np.where(mask==255, img_diff, img)

# save resulting masked image
cv2.imwrite('writer_balanced.jpg', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow("IMAGE", img)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
mean of inner region: 195.44008004122423
mean of outer region: 154.1415758021116
difference: 41.298504239112646
```

Result:

[image]

You can change the bias to make the inner region lighter or darker over all.

**ADDITION**

Here is the next order of improvement. Simply measure the darkest area inside and outside close to each other and then do the same for the brightest areas. Then compute a linear transformation of intensities from the measurements and apply to the image. Then use the mask to mix the two images.

This is similar to what @Christoph Rackwitz proposed. Except he did very rigorous computation and I simply did some visual measurements.

So for example, here are the places that I measured:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image 
img = cv2.imread('writer.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# rectangle coordinates
x = 62
y = 8
w = 662
h = 401
    
# create mask for inner area
mask = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.uint8)
mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = 255

# measure darkest and lightest neighboring regions inside and outside mask area of input
# darkest from chair in lower right
# brightest from background wall in upper left 
in1=95
out1=8
in2=250
out2=250

# compute linear transformation equation coefficients
# let x1=in1, y1=out1, x2=in2, y2=out2
# y1=a*x1+b
# y2=a*x2+b
# y2-y1 = a*(x2-x1)
# a = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
# b = y2 - a*x2

x1 = in1
y1 = out1 
x2 = in2
y2 = out2
a = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
b = y2 - a*x2
print("a:", a, "b:", b)

# process image with linear transformation
modified = (a * img.astype(np.float64) + b).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# blend with original using mask
result = np.where(mask==255, modified, img)

# save resulting masked image
cv2.imwrite('writer_balanced2.jpg', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow("IMAGE", img)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

here's my best attempt:

[image: result]

Grayscale histograms of the reference area, and the area to fix:

[image: histograms]

You see, the blending with white caused the histogram to be squeezed and moved rightward. An original value of 255 was mapped to 255, but the darker the original value, the more it is brightened. The mask area contains samples of presumably black (the backrest) that are also black in the untouched reference area, so we can estimate what's going on... original black was mapped to a grayscale value of ~88.

I find the minima in both spectra and use those for a linear mapping:

```py
refmax = 255
refmin = gray[~mask].min()
fixmax = 255
fixmin = gray[mask].min()

composite = im.copy()
composite[mask] = np.clip((composite[mask] - fixmin) / (fixmax - fixmin) * (refmax - refmin) + refmin, 0, 255)
```

And that's it.

Comment: don't really understand but i'll try to look for more information on this. thanks!